# Apple ID Sharing with daughter

Tags: iphone, apple-id, contacts

My daughter and I both have apple phones and up until about 1 month ago she was always logged in on her device using my apple id.

I am trying to find out does this give her access to make any changes on my phone (not necessarily on purpose or even knowingly).  Specifically, under contacts, where my name is listed, right under my last name was listed a nick name that I didn't put there.

Could she have some how on her phone updated my either her name and it transferred over to my name because of the sharing issue?  Or if she was talking to Siri and she asked Siri to call her something, could that have updated to both her name and to mine?

I'm trying to figure out how it got there when I didn't put it there, or how to avoid that problem in the future.

Comment: I would stay out this potentially explosive family problem, but just to say the system does not know it is her, it thinks you have 2 devices under same account.

Comment: Unless you used the Family sharing, then you have control over what she can and can not do.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense about the it thinks I had 2 device under the same account.  This is probably why I would see her calls under my call log.

Comment: And no we didn't have the family sharing plan.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent future problems, disable the current set up (where you have second device under Apple ID, but it is actually your daughter).

Just change the password on your Apple ID so she can not log in to that.

Then set her up as Family sharing, where you have some control over her account.

[Follow Apple Instructions on how to](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201088).